# MIME type of .mjs files is "text/html" when deploying React (ViteJS) app to Azure Kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, mime-types, azure-aks, mjs

I've built a React application utilizing ViteJS with TypeScript. I've built the project using `tsc && vite build`. I've then built the Docker image based on my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.12.0
COPY build /build
RUN npm i -g serve
CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-p", "5173"]
HEALTHCHECK CMD wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider http://localhost:5173/ || exit 1
```

I've tested the Docker Image locally, and it builds as intended and when run the container boots up and the application is accessible and wors as it should.

I've been following Microsofts documentation for utilizing an Nginx Ingress Controller: [Create an ingress controller in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli)

So, my manifest for this service looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld-one  
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aks-helloworld-one
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aks-helloworld-one
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aks-helloworld-one
        image: ghcr.io/akusasdesign/localizer:test-serve
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5173
        env:
        - name: TITLE
          value: "Welcome to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: github-container-registry
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld-one  
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 5173
  selector:
    app: aks-helloworld-one
```

The service and Deployment are both created, but when moving to the url, the page is white/blank. Checking the console I can see the error message:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I've done some searching, but can't find a reason/fix for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIME type for `.mjs` files needs to be `text/javascript`.
For more innformation check out the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#aside_%E2%80%94_.mjs_versus_.js) about that topic.

Comment: I can understand that since React is a Javascript framework. But why does it run smoothly locally, but this error happens in kubernetes?

Comment: It's hard to say but I would guess that your local environment has the correct MIME type setting for `.mjs` files and your kubernetes server does not.

Comment: That fixed it. The kubernetes cluster needed to be configured to handle it

Comment: @Akusas can you please share your solution and where u configued it?

Answer (score 0):

where can you configure this on kubernetes ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).